# Error en base de datos (android studio )sql

Tags: android, sql, base-de-datos

table products has no column named direc
10-08 14:25:09.403 939-939/com.example.arturosv.problem E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Numero=6.0 direc=gh Tel=67.0 name=a

Codigo main principal

```
package com.example.arturosv.problem;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // declaración de variables
    private EditText númeroCliente,nombreCliente,Telefono,Direccion;

    // Database Handler
    private DB BaseDatos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Asignación de variables
        númeroCliente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.númeroCliente);
        nombreCliente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombreCliente);
        Telefono = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Telefono);
        Direccion= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Direccion);

        // Instancia del objeto DB Handler
        BaseDatos = new DB (this, null, null, 1);
    }
    public void addProduct(View v){
        String name = nombreCliente.getText().toString();
        double numero = Double.parseDouble(númeroCliente.getText().toString());
        double telefono = Double.parseDouble(Telefono.getText().toString());
        String direccion=Direccion.getText().toString();

        Datos dato = new Datos (numero,direccion,telefono,name);

        BaseDatos.addProduct(dato);
        númeroCliente.setText("");
        nombreCliente.setText("");
        Telefono.setText("");
        Direccion.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Se añadió un nuevo dato",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("Duplou", "Se añadió un producto");
    }

    public void findProduct(View v){
        String name = nombreCliente.getText().toString();

        Datos dato = BaseDatos.findProduct(name);

        if(dato == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No se encontró el producto",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Duplou", "No se encontró el producto");
        }else{
            nombreCliente.setText(dato.getName());
            númeroCliente.setText(Double.toString(dato.getNúmero()));
            Telefono.setText(Double.toString(dato.getTel()));
            Direccion.setText(dato.getDirec());
           Log.d("Duplou", "Id: " + dato.getId() + " - Nombre: " + dato.getName() + " - Precio: " + dato.getNúmero()+ "telefono: " + dato.getTel());
        }
    }

    public void deleteProduct(View v){
        String name = nombreCliente.getText().toString();

        boolean productoBorrado = BaseDatos.deleteProduct(name);

        if(productoBorrado){
            nombreCliente.setText("");
            númeroCliente.setText("");
            Telefono.setText("");
            Direccion.setText("");
            Log.d("Duplou", "Se borró el producto");
        }else{
            Log.d("Duplou", "El producto que se intentó borrar no existe");
        }

    }
}
```

Codigo de DB.java ( aqui creo mi base )

package com.example.arturosv.problem;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_Numero = "Numero";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_TELEFONO = "Tel";
public static final String COLUMN_DIRECCION="direc";

public DB (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION); // Crea la BD
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Query para crear la tabla de productos
    String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS  + " ("+ COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COLUMN_Numero + " DOUBLE," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"+ COLUMN_TELEFONO + " DOUBLE, "+ COLUMN_DIRECCION + " TEXT )";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);

    onCreate(db);
}
// Función para añadir un producto nuevo a la BD
public void addProduct(Datos dato){
    // Contenedor de valores para la base de datos
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    // Configuramos lo valores del contenedor
    values.put(COLUMN_Numero, dato.getNúmero());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, dato.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_TELEFONO, dato.getTel());
    values.put(COLUMN_DIRECCION, dato.getDirec());

    // Obtenemos el objeto de la base de datos escribible
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // Insertamos el objeto en la BD
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
}
// Función para encontrar producto
public Datos findProduct(String name){

    // Hacemos el query
    String findQuery =
            "SELECT * FROM " +
                    TABLE_PRODUCTS  +
                    " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME +
                    " = " + "\"" + name + "\"";

    // Obtenemos el objeto de la base de datos escribible
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // Objeto que almacena el resultado
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(findQuery,null);

    // Creamos un objeto de tipo producto
    Datos dato = new Datos ();

    // Checamos si existe un resultado de la búsqueda
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        dato.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        dato.setNúmero(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(1)));
        dato.setName(cursor.getString(2));
        dato.setTel(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
        dato.setDirec(cursor.getString(4));;
    }else{
        dato = null;
    }

    cursor.close();

    return dato;
}

// Función para borrar un elemento
public boolean deleteProduct(String name){
    boolean deleted = false; // inicializamos la bandera de "borrado"

    // Se hace el query para buscar el objeto
    String findQuery =
            "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS +
                    " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " = " +
                    "\"" + name + "\"";

    // Obtenemos el objeto de la base de datos escribible
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // Objeto que almacena el resultado
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(findQuery, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        String deleteQuery =
                "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS +
                        " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " = " +
                        "\"" + name + "\"";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(deleteQuery); // se ejecuta el query

        cursor.close(); // finaliza el uso del cursor

        deleted = true;
    }

    return deleted;
}
```

}

3.-Datos.java ( los constructures )

```
package com.example.arturosv.problem;

/**
 * Created by ArturoSV on 08/10/2016.
 */
public class Datos {
    // Propiedades de un producto
    private int _id;
    private double _número;
    private String _name;
    private double _Tel;
    private String _direc;
    // Constructor simple
    public Datos() {
    }
    // Constructor nombre y precio

    //numero,direccion,telefono,name
    public Datos(double número, String direc, double Tel,String name) {
        this._número = número;
        this._name = name;
        this._Tel = Tel;
        this._direc=direc;
    }
    // Constructor con todos los parámetros
    public Datos (int id,double número, String direc, double Tel,String name) {
        this._id = id;
        this._número = número;
        this._name = name;
        this._Tel = Tel;
        this._direc=direc;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }
    public double getNúmero() {
        return _número;
    }
    public void setNúmero(double número) {
        this._número = número;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return _name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this._name = name;
    }
    public double getTel() {
        return _Tel;
    }
    public void setTel(double Tel) {
        this._Tel = Tel;
    }

    public String getDirec() {
        return _direc;
    }

    public void setDirec(String direc) {
        this._direc = direc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero si lo estas probando en el emulador en ir a data-data y borrar la bd creada por la app e intentarlo nuevamente.

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta especificado en:

> table products has no column named direc

Revisa la creación de tu tabla `productos` no contiene una columna llamada `direc`.

Veo que tu query crea el campo especificado.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
            // Query para crear la tabla de productos 
        String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " ("+ COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_Numero + " DOUBLE," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"+ COLUMN_TELEFONO + " DOUBLE, "+ COLUMN_DIRECCION + " TEXT )";
     db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE); 
}
```

Seguramente se creo incorrectamente en alguna prueba anterior.

Elimina la aplicación y prueba nuevamente, ya que de esta forma se llamaría el método `onCreate()`, el cual crearía nuevamente la correcta estructura de tu tabla.